# What's the right way to add ImageResizer to an IIS virtual folder

Tags: imageresizer

My ASP.NET contains an IIS virtual folder that points to static images (so that the HTTP requests serving up these images do not even touch my app).

To web clients consuming my site at `http://<server>/myAppRoot`:

```
Page1.aspx
Page2.aspx
images/MyAppLogo.png
static/file1.png <-- IIS virtual folder "static" points to D:\someOtherPath
static/file2.png
```

On the server filesystem at C:\somePath\myAppRoot:

```
Global.asax
Page1.aspx
Page2.aspx
Web.config
bin\MyAppAssembly.dll
bin\ImageResizer.dll
images\MyAppLogo.png
```

And elsewhere on the server live all the static images at D:\someOtherPath:

```
file1.png
file2.png
```

I can add ImageResizer to the ASP.NET bin folder, along side my own assemblies, and add the `<resizer>` tag to Web.config, ImageResizer will run and process any request from my actual app folder. I can use all the ImageResizer stunts to make MyAppLogo.png dance.

But ImageResizer won't recognize intercept any requests for the `/static/` virtual folder (which is the folder containing tons of uploaded images that I want small thumbnails for on the fly).

How do I configure ImageResizer to process the `/static/` virtual folder?

I should add that `/static/` is added by our installer, completely outside of our app, and is not a `<location>` tag inside my app's Web.config.

Any suggestions on how to configure ImageResizer to process the `/static/` IIS virtual folder?

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, ImageResizer **should** work with IIS virtual path providers.

However, there is the VirtualFolder plugin, which is available for free. See http://imageresizing.net/plugins/virtualfolder . Note the caveat:

> IIS Virtual Folders perform better, however, so this plugin should only be used for testing, development, or as a last resort.

I have no personal experience on the plugin but the configuration seems easy; you'll just need to map virtual paths to physical paths like this:

```
<add name="VirtualFolder" virtualPath="~/static/" physicalPath="D:\someOtherPath" vpp="false "/>
```

Comment: No, that's not it. I can't use the `VirtualFolder` plugin, since it's not meant for production deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, testing the access attempts to the `myAppRoot/static/*` paths directly on the webserver revealed a much more detailed IIS error (403.1 Forbidden).

The `/static/` folder had been previously configured with "Read" access, when it needed "Script" access.

Solution:

Modify the `<handlers>` of `<system.webServer>` in `D:\someOtherPath\Web.config` to `<handlers accessPolicy="Script" />`